# callback url not being executed with google passport strategy oAuth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I have tried nearly everything (read threads,searched on google) but i don't understand why is my callback url not being executed.After debugging, i found that the request is being sent to google servers, i get back the profile.But the callback is not being executed.The page just hangs there as soon as i navigate to http:\localhost:3000\auth\google.I am using a localhost server currently.
Although the data is being persisted on mongodb which means that the route is working but not the callback.

Below are my routes and local strategy.

AuthRoutes.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
module.exports = app => {
  app.get("/auth/google/", (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate("google", {

      scope: ["profile", "email"] 
    });
  });

  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      successRedirect: "/profile",
      failureRedirect: "/"
    })
  );

  app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);

  });

  app.get("/api/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/completed"); 
  });
};
```

passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const keys = require("../config/keys");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = mongoose.model("users");

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id); 
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(userModel => {
    done(null, userModel);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: keys.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
      proxy: true
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
      User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then(existinguser => {
        if (existinguser) {
          //done(null, existinguser);
        } else {
          new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save().then(user => {
            //  done(null, user);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Feel free to ask anything that i have missed.
Thanks.

Comment: Which functions are and are not being executed?

Comment: The /auth/google/callback route